# Open accented xml file with python

Tags: python, xml, file-io, glob

I have this bit of code

```
for xmlword in moviexmlfind:
                    fileinfo = jukeboxpath + xmlword + "*.xml"
                    for name in glob.glob(fileinfo):
```

If an xmlword contains an accented letter it will error saying character not in range.

I have also tried:

```
if lookfor in open(lookfor + '.xml').read():
```

but that throws up encoding errors.

How can I code it to open accented file names?

Comment: Do include the *full* exception message. What is `moviexmlfind`? Does it contain Unicode values?

Comment: moviexmlfind is a list of search terms so that can find all matching file names, 1 item is Other_All, this it to match against Other_All_1.xml, Other_All_2.xml ect. The only glob error i get is the one i posted, ideally i would like to have that part work as it would save adding in a new section. They are utf-8 strings

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new detail. Include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: with the second method i get No such file or directory: 'Ast\xc3\xa9rix et Ob\xc3\xa9lix au service de Sa Majest\xc3\xa9

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs
codecs.open("some/file/with/unicode","rb",encoding="utf8")
```

should work fine :)  (assuming its utf8 encoding in the file)

also I think your problem is that you are just giving the filename without the path try `os.path.join(jukeboxpath,xml_file_name)` as your path instead of just xml_file_name